# How to answer http request redirected to localhost

Tags: redirection, ip-address, localhost

I am redirecting a request to local host by editing my host file as such :
127.0.0.1                   web-sls.tera.gameforge.com

Now I understood that the request that was previously sent to web-sls.tera.gameforge.com is now redirected to my localhost, but what I don't understand is how I receive this request and answer to it ?
Do I simply code a server program that listens to the http port and run it on the same computer that has its host modified ?
thanks

Comment: "Do I simply code a server program that listens to the http port and run it on the same computer that has its host modified" Yes.

Comment: Meh, although it's logic i thought there would be more to it, thanks for confirming.